# Removing a background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, background, white

Trying to remove the back ground on this image but because its white on white the Magic wand, Quick Selection and Magic eraser tool won't pick it up. I know I could sit and eraser it all with a brush tool but I can't do it in a straight line because of the shape of the product. Is then any other way? I've tried different layers with brighter backgrounds etccc

[image]

Comment: With an object like this I think I would use `Pen tool`. Just draw a path around it and create a `vector mask`

Comment: Yes, i would use the pen tool or the lasso!

Answer (score 0):

Use either the pen tool and convert the path to a selection or use the lasso tool. This shape is pretty simple.

If you have trouble distinguishing the borders, you can duplicate your layer, darken or exagerate the contrast, use it as a reference and when you have the mask, just delete that reference layer.